# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector') at xhr.onload web scraping

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

script.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
const $prod = document.getElementById("prod");
const $precio = document.getElementById("precio");

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/url", true);
xhr.responseType = "document";

xhr.onload = function(){
    /*if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){*/
        let response = xhr.responseXML.querySelector(".className");
        console.log(response);
    /*}*/
};

xhr.onerror = function(){
    console.error(xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
}

xhr.send();


})
```

I am trying to web scrape a web page, but when running the code, it throws the error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector') at xhr.onload. I have checked if I have placed the selector correctly but apparently the error would not be there.
If someone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why is the `readyState` and `status` check commented out?

Comment: @Cerbrus — Since the load event only fires in state 4 when the request is successful, a better question would be why it is there in the first place.

Comment: @Quentin: Probably copied from a tutorial?

Comment: Hi, yes I copied from a tutorial but don't work. I will try fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that `xhr.responseXML` is `null`. The selector is irrelevant, it doesn't get that far.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest):

> **XMLHttpRequest.responseXML** Read only
>
> Returns a Document containing the response to the request, or **null if the request was unsuccessful, has not yet been sent, or cannot be parsed as XML or HTML**.

Since the load event fired, the request *should* be both sent and successful, so there was a problem parsing it.

Look at the response in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools to start debugging this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try to follow your advice.